# Isomorphic Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and the ideal $M_n(2\mathbb{Z})$. My question is
$$M_n(\mathbb{Z})/M_n(\mathbb{2Z})\approx\ ?$$

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, it would seem that each matrix filled with $0$s and $1$ is in a different coset from all the others, and every integer matrix is in a coset with one of them, so that gives you a cardinality of $2^n$. Is that right?

Comment: I mean, $2^{n^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $f : M_n(\Bbb{Z}) \to M_n(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$ which sends a matrix $M$ to the same matrix, but with entries modulo $2$. Is $f$ surjective? What is the kernel of $f$?